# XML short code returns error message, why?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I wrote the following code in XML:

```
<# <Conditional Test= "(//Product_Name[text() = ‘LifeID3 Service’ and //Customer_Is_Paying_Maintenance/text())" /> #>
```

DisplayThisText

`<# <EndConditional/> #>`

Somehow I get the following error message:

> `(//Product_Name[text() = 'LifeID3 Service' and //Customer_Is_Paying_Maintenance/text())'` has an invalid token.

Could you please tell me where is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

An XML element name may not begin with `#`, so `<#` is not permitted in [*well-formed*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134494/290085) XML, so

> I wrote the following code in XML:
>
> `<# <Conditional Test= "(//Product_Name[text() = ‘LifeID3 Service’ and //Customer_Is_Paying_Maintenance/text())" /> #>`

is not correct — that's not XML.

However, if the `<#` construct is particular to some (unspecified) application, perhaps you can proceed if you repair the syntax error in what appears to be an XPath with a predicate closed by `)` rather than `]`:

```
... [text() = 'LifeID3 Service' and //Customer_Is_Paying_Maintenance/text())
                                                                           ^
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a cut-and-paste problem, but those delimiters around ‘LifeID3 Service’ are not apostrophes, they are typographical quotation marks.